# SearchDomainFactory.Instance is obsolete: 'Inject me!' ( Can't find out how to create instance)

Tags: resharper, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

I'm in the process of trying to migrate a R# extension project from R# 6 to R# 8. (I've taken over a project that someone wrote, and I'm new to writing extensions.)

In the existing v6 project there is a class that derives from RenameWorkflow, and the constructor used to look like this;

```
public class RenameStepWorkflow : RenameWorkflow
{
    public RenameStepWorkflow(ISolution Solution, string ActionId) 
        : base(Solution, ActionId)
    {
    }
```

This used to work in R# SDK v 6, but now in V8, RenameWorkflow no longer has a constructor that takes Solution and actionId. The new constructor signature now looks like this;

```
    public RenameWorkflow(
IShellLocks locks, 
SearchDomainFactory searchDomainFactory, 
RenameRefactoringService renameRefactoringService, 
ISolution solution, 
string actionId);
```

*now heres my problem that I need help with (I think)*

I've copied the constructor, and now the constructor of this class has to satisfy these new dependancies. Through some digging I've managed to find a way to satisfy all the dependencies, except for **'SearchDomainFactory'**. The closest I can come to instantiating via the updated constructor is as follows;

new RenameStepWorkflow(Solution.Locks, JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Search.SearchDomainFactory.Instance, RenameRefactoringService.Instance, this.Solution, null)

All looks good, except that `JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Search.SearchDomainFactory.Instance` is marked as Obsolete, and gives me a compile error that I cannot work around, even using `#pragma` does not allow me to compile the code. The exact error message I get when I compile is `Error 16  'JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Search.SearchDomainFactory.Instance' is obsolete: 'Inject me!'`

Obvious next question..ok, how? How do I 'inject you'? I cannot find any documentation over this new breaking change, in fact, I cannot find any documentation (or sample projects) that even mentions `DrivenRefactoringWorkflow` or `RenameWorkflow`, (the classes that now require the new SearchDomainFactory), or any information on `SearchDomainFactory.Instance` suddenly now obsolete and how to satisfy the need to 'inject' it.

Any help would be most appreciated!  Thank you,

regards

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper has its own IoC container, which is responsible for creating instances of classes, and "injecting" dependencies as constructor parameters. Classes marked with attributes such as `[ShellComponent]` or `[SolutionComponent]` are handled by the container, created when the application starts or a solution is loaded, respectively.

Dependencies should be injected as constructor parameters, rather than using methods like `GetComponent<TDependency>` or static `Instance` properties, as this allows the container to control dependency lifetime, and ensure you're depending on appropriate components, and not creating leaks - a shell component cannot depend on a solution component for instance, it won't exist when the shell component is being created.

ReSharper introduced the IoC container a few releases ago, and a large proportion of the codebase has been updated to use it correctly, but there are a few hold-outs, where things are still done in a less than ideal manner - static `Instance` properties and calls to `GetComponent`. This is what you've encountered. You should be able to get an instance of `SearchDomainFactory` by putting it as a constructor parameter in your component.

You can find out more about the Component Model (the IoC container and related functionality) in the devguide: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Platform/ComponentModel.html